# How to read the StackTrace?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

I hope this question can survive the rules of SO, as I searched a lot, didn't find a documentation on it, and sometimes ignored it, but that drove me to not understanding the problem nor the solution. the `StackeTrace` of the Exceptoion has its own way of describing the problem, yes in a human-friendly language but with symbols and code that I don't know about or where it comes from, this is one of these that I ignored because I don't understand what it says, but I can't solve the problem:

> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext ()
>   [0x004ab] in <35658e59c86d40bdbb2ef0bb34b4f0c7>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000ca] in <35658e59c86d40bdbb2ef0bb34b4f0c7>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   PSProject.Helpers.Utility+d__15.MoveNext () [0x00136] in
>   D:\PSProject\PSProject\PSProject\PSProject\Helpers\Utility.cs:212

The exception is thrown when I try to to Get data through a webservice via `HttpClient.PostAsync` from a Wi-Fi network, not mobile data (this is a Xamarin app).
What can I understand from that trace? 
For example:

1. What is the `HttpClientHandler`
   and where it is located:

> in <35658e59c86d40bdbb2ef0bb34b4f0c7>

2. This was mentioned two times:

> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown

Is this an internal code for `HttpClient` class?

How to get know the most of the StackTrace to understand the exception?

Comment: The answer for question 1 is: the `HttpClientHandler` is a class to implementations of HTTP handler.

Comment: are you using  mono ?

Comment: Some info about these lines could be found in [Environment,StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) and also in the [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) class examples

Comment: @ilansch sorry but I'm beginning Xamarin, didn't know a lot about mono (I thought it's totally abstracted )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack tracer is complicated because you are using `async/await`. You do not need most of the information from the above trace. Mostly you are ok to ignore the error codes and anything related to `awaiter`.

Find the first position where the `awaiter` is not mentioned, and mostly you are going to find a line number over there. It is mostly the position which threw the `Exception` you are investigating.

In your example it is this line:

> PSProject.Helpers.Utility+d__15.MoveNext () [0x00136] in D:\PSProject\PSProject\PSProject\PSProject\Helpers\Utility.cs:212

It is the first position where the `awaiter` is not mentioned. The line number in *Utility.cs* file which threw the `Exception` is *212*.